# Deep Associative Array to adjacent mysql table

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

Been fighting the whole night. Giving up. I have an adjacent table in mysql:

```
id, parentid,name,design,path,sort
```

The depth is maximum four and using mysql query, I print out the results to UL list successfully. From there, items are added, sorted and edited as well as removed. Then when button is clicked, I send the result back to php. The data been sent is JSON and it does get recieved.

`json_decode()` gives the following sample:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [cls] => [path] => # [id] => 1 [name] =>BLOCKA  ) [1] => Array ( [cls] => [path] => # [id] => 2 [name] => BLOCKB [children] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [cls] => [path] => # [id] => 3 [name] => CLASSB1 [children] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [cls] => [path] => # [id] => 7 [name] => CLASSB12 ) ) ) [1] => Array ( [cls] => [path] => # [id] => 4 [name] => CLASSSB13 [children] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [cls] => [path] => # [id] => 5 [name] => CLASSB4 ) [1] => Array ( [cls] => [path] => # [id] => 6 [name] => CLASSB5 ) ) ) ) ) )
```

Graphically:

`BLOCKA
 BLOCKB
  CLASSB1
  CLASSB3
...`

I am using `jquery.nested`

Now my problem is looping through the array, getting id of the parent then add child.

The closest I came with is

```
function dissect($blocks) {
    if (!is_array($blocks)) {
        echo $blocks;
        return;
    }

    foreach($blocks as $block) {
        dissect($block);
    }
}
```

It does process each element but not in the way I want. Sorry for my broken english...any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First iterate through blocks getting the parent, if children exists in parent block, loop through the children.

There might be other better way to implement this, you can try below code:

```
$blocks = array ( 
"0" => array ( 
    "cls" => "",
    "path" => array( 
        "id" => 1,
        "name" =>"BLOCKA",
        ) 
    ), 
"1" => array ( 
    "cls" => "",
    "path" => array( 
        "id" => 2,
        "name" => "BLOCKB" ,
        "children" => array ( 
            "0" => array ( 
                "cls" => "",
                "path" => array( 
                    "id" => 3,
                    "name" => "CLASSB1" ,
                    "children" => array ( 
                        "0" => array ( 
                            "cls" => "",
                            "path" => array( 
                                "id" => 7,
                                "name" => "CLASSB12" ,
                                ),
                            ),
                        ), 
                    ),
                ),
            "1" => array ( 
                "cls" => "",
                "path" => array( 
                    "id" => 4,
                    "name" => "CLASSSB13" ,
                    "children" => array ( 
                        "0" => array ( 
                            "cls" => "",
                            "path" => array( 
                                "id" => 5,
                                "name" => "CLASSB4" ,
                                ),
                            ), 
                        "1" => array ( 
                            "cls" => "",
                            "path" => array( 
                                "id" => 6,
                                "name" => "CLASSB5",
                                ), 
                            ), 
                        ), 
                    ),
                ), 
            ),
        ), 
    ), 
) ;

echo "<pre>";

/*loop through blocks*/
foreach ($blocks as $key => $block) {
    echo $block['path']['name'].'<br/>'; /* echo parent*/
    if (isset($block['path']['children'])) {
        loopChildren($block['path']['children']); /* children loop*/
    }
}

/*Loop through childrens*/
function loopChildren($childrens, $prefix = '-')
{
    foreach ($childrens as $key => $child) {
        getChild($child, $prefix);
    }
}

/*Get the child and loop sub-children if exist*/
function getChild($child, $prefix='-')
{ 
    echo $prefix. $child['path']['name'].'<br/>'; /*echo child*/
    if (isset($child['path']['children'])) {
        $prefix .= '-';
        loopChildren($child['path']['children'], $prefix); /* sub-children loop*/
    }
}

echo "</pre>";
```

**The output:**

```
BLOCKA
BLOCKB
-CLASSB1
--CLASSB12
-CLASSSB13
--CLASSB4
--CLASSB5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That looks functional. Lemme try it in an hour and get back to you.

Comment: @NieSelam I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your tip. It guided me to an answer that worked for me. I ended up using two functions. The error was "index out of bound"...here is what I did now...with calls to the mysql table:

```
$response = json_decode($_POST['s'], true); // decoding received JSON to array
if(is_array($response)){


//start saving now
$order=1;
 foreach ($response as $key => $block) {
  //0 is for blocks: no parent id needed
 $parentid=$this->Blocks_model->insertblock($block['name'],$block['cls'],0,$block['path'],$order);

if (isset($block['children'])) {


   $this->childblocks($parentid,$block['children']);


}

$order++;
}


}

private function childblocks($parentid,$e){
$order=1;
foreach ($e as $key => $block) {
$parentid=$this->Blocks_model->insertblock($block['name'],$block['cls'],0,$block['path'],$order);


if (isset($block['children'])) {

$this->childblocks($parentid,$block['children']);

}
$order++;

}


}
```